# Is my cat fat or does she just have saggy breasts?

Tags: cats, health, weight

The title should say it all, but to add to it: she hasn't been seen by a vet for a few years, but last time she was there the vet thought she was in good health and just a, "larger" cat and not fat. Since then she appears to have slowly gotten what appears to be either a very saggy belly or very saggy rear-breasts.

She is spayed and has been since early youth. She quite active for an indoor cat and has a healthy eating habit (e.g. She grazes throughout the day and doesn't overeat). She has no signs of any kind of illness what-so-ever, including any behavioral or activity changes. She can jump quite high despite the extra baggage in the back and is very agile.

Specifically, the baggage is right where he furthermost rear nipples are, which is large why I am having a hard time determining which it is. Also, her other breasts are totally normal.

Comment: when you say saggy breasts i wonder if this is only the belly skin of your cat that is a little loose or if this is enlarged mamary glands,if it is the later you need to get your cat to the vet.https://www.wikihow.com/Determine-if-Your-Cat-is-Overweight

Comment: Your description makes it "sound" like excess weight... but "a picture is worth a thousand words". Can you post one so we can see if there might be other explanations? Does the area feel like lose skin or like there is something inside it?

Comment: That sounds like the "apron," a saggy-looking bit of skin at the belly that many cats get without ever being fat. If it feels loose, and the cat still has the proper feel and body shape for an appropriate weight, it's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the Wikihow article that trond hanson posted, #5:

> Do not be overly concerned about a saggy belly. Many cats have a saggy
>   bit of flesh that hangs down between their back legs. If your cat is
>   otherwise bony, this small pouch of skin is unlikely to be an
>   indication of a weight problem. This skin flap is referred to as the
>   "primordial pouch" and its purpose is to protect the stomach during
>   fights with other cats. Cats often kick with their back legs when
>   angry, and this flap of skin protects your cat from such attacks. Many
>   cats will develop a primordial pouch at some point in their lives and
>   it is not necessarily an indicator of feline obesity.

Since my cat passes the other tests, this sounds like the answer since it is exactly what she has.

Comment: The fat in the lower belly on cats is also sometimes called the apron. Cats naturally tend to gain fat there, and once gained, even if the cat gets thinner, the skin will still hang there, so, yes, it's not a good indicator of obesity.

Comment: These skin flaps are sometimes very pronounced and can look funny/unusual but yes they are totally normal. There are a number of ideas about the flap’s role. A cat’s spine can extend and contract giving them extra power when running and jumping and maybe the extra skin facilitates this.

Answer (score 4):

If your cat looks like this, it is normal. This is Trine. She is 13 years old and weighs 4,5 kilos.[image]

You can see the loose part of skin in front of her hind leg. I know she looks a little bulky on this picture, but it is a result of a cold spring day and cold wind making her look fluffy (the white stuff is snow, LOL).

You say your cat has not been to the vet for some time. My advice is to visit the vet at least every two years when the cat is young and every year for older cats. And be sure the vaccines are up to date.

It would have been helpful if you had posted a picture of your cat. It is easier to see the cat than it is to explain how it looks.

Here is [a link on how to tell if your cat is "normal"](https://www.cathealth.com/cat-care/weight-management/1255-cat-check-weight).

When you look at the cat from above and are able to see your cat's waist, your cat is within normal weight, and if you can feel your cat's spine and ribs, it is not obese.

The muscle tone and the body will change over time in cats in the same way as it does for people(gravity is not our friend).